# Trying to numerically match python Log-Mel Spectrogram in Accelerate / Swift

Tags: python, audio, fft, accelerate-framework, openai-whisper

[I am working on a native port](https://github.com/tanmayb123/OpenAI-Whisper-CoreML/pull/2) of OpenAI's Whisper for macOS and iOS via CoreML and Accelerate / AVFoundation, and in doing so noticed numerical differences in my Log Mel Spectrogram and code Whispers.

[This python Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1r9ghakH8__jGqGiYHC2DXtKaW_ozdSrV?usp=sharing) extracts the Log Mel Spectrogram exactly how Whisper does. I've decomposed the steps clearly.

My Swift code matches:

- Raw Audio Samples
- Conversion to Float
- Conversion to Normalized Float
- Hamming Windows calculated
- Loading the precomputed Mel Filters

What begins to differ:

- Complex Numbers from the STFT process
- Results of Matrix ops.

However when I do my windowed FFTs, I notice similar values ranges, but inconsistent values that dont seem to match remotely. As in, not a rounding error.

[My Full Mel class can be found here:](https://github.com/vade/OpenAI-Whisper-CoreML/blob/feature/AccelerateMEL/Whisper/Whisper/MelSpectrogram.swift)

The Python code I am trying to match:

```
    window = torch.hann_window(N_FFT).to(audio.device)
    stft = torch.stft(audio, N_FFT, HOP_LENGTH, window=window, return_complex=True)
    magnitudes = stft[:, :-1].abs() ** 2
    filters = mel_filters(audio.device, n_mels)
    mel_spec = filters @ magnitudes
    log_spec = torch.clamp(mel_spec, min=1e-10).log10()
    log_spec = torch.maximum(log_spec, log_spec.max() - 8.0)
    log_spec = (log_spec + 4.0) / 4.0
```

And the core section of my swift code:

Points of interest:

- Python appears to be outputting STFT of size 201 and 3001, whereas im not sure why they get 201, or 3001 from. My math seems to work out to generating 200 x 3000 exactly with the params from Whisper?
- Am I calculating the overlapping hops correctly? I am not merging them into a single FFT. Im also padding by 200 samples before and after my audio frame of samples.
- I am assuming that the 3000 sets 200 length complex numbers generated are STFT output output from PyTorch
- Im assuming that vDSP's FFT implementation more or less matches whatever is happening in PyTorch
- The STFT from Pytorch 0ths element and last element both have zero'd imaginary components. Mine do not. How!?

I know this is a large, complex question, but maybe someone brave will help me out?

Thank you in advance!

```
 func processData(audio: [Int16]) -> [Float]
    {
        assert(self.sampleCount == audio.count)
            
        var audioFloat:[Float] = [Float](repeating: 0, count: audio.count)
        vDSP.convertElements(of: audio, to: &audioFloat)
              
        vDSP.divide(audioFloat, 32768.0, result: &audioFloat)
        
        // insert numFFT/2 samples before and numFFT/2 after so we have a extra numFFT amount to process
        audioFloat.insert(contentsOf: [Float](repeating: 0, count: self.numFFT/2), at: 0)
        audioFloat.append(contentsOf: [Float](repeating: 0, count: self.numFFT/2))
        

        // Split Complex arrays holding the mel spectrogram
        var allSampleReal = [[Float]](repeating: [Float](repeating: 0, count: self.numFFT/2), count: self.melSampleCount)
        var allSampleImaginary = [[Float]](repeating: [Float](repeating: 0, count: self.numFFT/2), count: self.melSampleCount)

        // we need to create 200 x 3000 matrix of STFTs - note we appear to want to output complex numbers (?)
        for (i) in 0 ..< self.melSampleCount
        {
            // Slice numFFTs every hop count (barf) and make a mel spectrum out of it
            var audioFrame = Array<Float>( audioFloat[ (i * self.hopCount) ..< ( (i * self.hopCount) + self.numFFT) ] )
            
            assert(audioFrame.count == self.numFFT)
            
            // Split Complex arrays holding a single FFT result, which gets appended to the
            var sampleReal:[Float] = [Float](repeating: 0, count: self.numFFT/2)
            var sampleImaginary:[Float] = [Float](repeating: 0, count: self.numFFT/2)
            
            sampleReal.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { realPtr in
                sampleImaginary.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { imagPtr in
                    
                    vDSP.multiply(audioFrame,
                                  hanningWindow,
                                  result: &audioFrame)

                    var complexSignal = DSPSplitComplex(realp: realPtr.baseAddress!,
                                                        imagp: imagPtr.baseAddress!)
                           
                    audioFrame.withUnsafeBytes { unsafeAudioBytes in
                        vDSP.convert(interleavedComplexVector: [DSPComplex](unsafeAudioBytes.bindMemory(to: DSPComplex.self)),
                                     toSplitComplexVector: &complexSignal)
                    }
                    
                    self.fft.forward(input: complexSignal,
                                 output: &complexSignal)
                }
            }

            allSampleReal[i] = sampleReal
            allSampleImaginary[i] = sampleImaginary
        }
        
        // We create flattened  3000 x 200 array of DSPSplitComplex values
        var flattnedReal:[Float] = allSampleReal.flatMap { $0 }
        var flattnedImaginary:[Float] = allSampleImaginary.flatMap { $0 }

        // Take the magnitude squared of the matrix, which results in a Result flat array of 3000 x 200 of real floats
        // Then multiply it with our mel filter bank
        let count = flattnedReal.count
        var magnitudes = [Float](repeating: 0, count: count)
        var melSpectroGram = [Float](repeating: 0, count: 80 * 3000)
        
        flattnedReal.withUnsafeMutableBytes { unsafeReal in
            flattnedImaginary.withUnsafeMutableBytes { unsafeImaginary in
                
                let matrix = [DSPSplitComplex](repeating: DSPSplitComplex(realp: unsafeReal.bindMemory(to: Float.self).baseAddress!,
                                                                          imagp: unsafeImaginary.bindMemory(to: Float.self).baseAddress!),
                                               count: count)
                
                // populate magnitude matrix with magnitudes squared
                vDSP_zvmags(matrix, 1, &magnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(count))
                
                // transpose magnitudes to get our 200 x 3000 matrix
                vDSP_mtrans(magnitudes, 1, &magnitudes, 1, 3000, 200)
                
                // Matrix A, a MxK sized matrix
                // Matrix B, a KxN sized matrix
                
                // MATRIX A mel filters is 80 rows x 200 columns
                // MATRIX B magnitudes is 3000 x 200
                // MATRIX B is TRANSPOSED to be 200 rows x 3000 columns
                // MATRIX C melSpectroGram is 80 rows x 3000 columns
                
                let M: Int32 = 80 // number of rows in matrix A
                let N: Int32 = 3000 // number of columns in matrix B
                let K: Int32 = 200 // number of columns in matrix A and number of rows in
                
                // matrix multiply magitude squared matrix with our filter bank
                // see https://www.advancedswift.com/matrix-math/
                cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor,
                            CblasNoTrans,           // Transpose A
                            CblasNoTrans,           //
                            M,                      // M Number of rows in matrices A and C.
                            N,                      // N Number of columns in matrices B and C.
                            K,                      // K Number of columns in matrix A; number of rows in matrix B.
                            1.0,                    // Alpha Scaling factor for the product of matrices A and B.
                            self.melFilterMatrix,   // Matrix A
                            K,                      // LDA The size of the first dimension of matrix A; if you are passing a matrix A[m][n], the value should be m.
                            magnitudes,             // Matrix B
                            N,                      // LDB The size of the first dimension of matrix B; if you are passing a matrix B[m][n], the value should be m.
                            0,                      // Beta Scaling factor for matrix C.
                            &melSpectroGram,        // Matrix C
                            N)                      // LDC The size of the first dimension of matrix C; if you are passing a matrix C[m][n], the value should be m.
                //        }
                
                var minValue: Float = 1e-10
                var maxValue: Float = 0.0
                var maxIndex: vDSP_Length = 0
                var minIndex: vDSP_Length = 0
                
                let melCount = melSpectroGram.count
                
                // get the current max value
                vDSP_maxvi(melSpectroGram, 1, &maxValue, &maxIndex, vDSP_Length(melCount))
                
                // Clip to a set min value, keeping the current max value
                vDSP_vclip(melSpectroGram, 1, &minValue, &maxValue, &melSpectroGram, 1, vDSP_Length(melCount))
                
                // Take the log base 10
                var melCountInt32:UInt32 = UInt32(melCount)
                vvlog10f(&melSpectroGram, melSpectroGram, &melCountInt32)
                
                // get the new max value
                vDSP_maxvi(melSpectroGram, 1, &maxValue, &maxIndex, vDSP_Length(melCount))
                
                // get the new min value
                vDSP_minvi(melSpectroGram, 1, &minValue, &minIndex, vDSP_Length(melCount))
                
                // emulate
                // log_spec = torch.maximum(log_spec, log_spec.max() - 8.0)
                // we effectively clamp to max - 8.0
                var newMin = maxValue - 8.0
                
                // Clip to new max and updated min
                vDSP_vclip(melSpectroGram, 1, &newMin, &maxValue, &melSpectroGram, 1, vDSP_Length(melCount))
                
                // Add 4 and Divide by 4
                var four:Float = 4.0
                vDSP_vsadd(melSpectroGram, 1, &four, &melSpectroGram, 1, vDSP_Length(melCount))
                vDSP_vsdiv(melSpectroGram, 1, &four, &melSpectroGram, 1, vDSP_Length(melCount))
                
            }
        }
        
        return melSpectroGram
    }
```

Comment: Have you find the solution for the above problem?

Comment: Hi @Manvi - not specifically for vDSP, but there is a functioning 'software' (read, non SIMD, non vectorized) rFFT that matches PyTorch in the RosaKit swift project. Be sure to pass accelerated=false or you get (as I've seen) incorrect values.